# SQl Server insert Special characters

Tags: sql

hi i m trying to insert `'s` in SQL sever i have search on solution to Replace `'s` to `''s` then insert it is it valid solution or give me other solution

Comment: What are you using to insert the data into your DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are going to insert values with single quote `'`, you have to escape it through single quote. So what you are doing is right.

You may see this article: [SQL SERVER – How to Escape Single Quotes](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/17/sql-server-how-to-escape-single-quotes-fix-error-105-unclosed-quotation-mark-after-the-character-string/)